# How to do install the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for Android Studio?

Tags: 12.04, android

I want to install Android stuido for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

But I don't know how to make PATH

I search Google But I don't know how to make PATH

Install linux for Android Studio I'm make PATH

Do you know how to install the Android Studio 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 3):

You can search on Google for android studio ubuntu, and there are several sites with instructions, e.g.:

http://www.cnx-software.com/2013/05/16/installing-android-studio-ide-in-ubuntu-hello-world-application/

http://darrylclarke.com/2013/05/17/a-quickie-on-using-android-studio-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I clicked the first link, then from there clicked a link in the second paragraph entitled "Android Studio Installation instructions"